# Checking IF condition then bypass it to ELSE

Tags: java, android, if-statement, conditional-statements

I have a block of IF ELSE condition statement. Let's say that this is my code

How do I get to the **IF ELSE of isTrue** of code without changing the **A or B**?
I tried **return true** but It wouldn't return because it's in a method. Is there any keyword to do so?

```
public void test() {
 if (text1.equals("") {
   //Output error message
 } else if (text2.equals("") { 
   //Ouput error message
 .
 .
 .
 } else if (A!= null && (A > B))  {
   //GO TO ELSE condition without changing the A or B
 } else { if (isTrue){} }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Take the last conditional out of the other conditionals:

```
public void test() {
   if (text1.equals("") {
      //Output error message
   } else if (text2.equals("") { 
      //Ouput error message
   } else if (A!= null && (A > B))  {
      //GO TO ELSE condition without changing the A or B
   }

   if (isTrue){ }
}
```

Comment: Let's say I want to keep it like the original, is there any keyword to use? Like for bypassing it.

Comment: Yes `continue;`

Comment: continue; only works in loop

Comment: This solution will _always_ check isTrue() which is far from what the code OP posted does.

Answer (score 0):

Looks for me like you try to return a boolean with that method to check any parameter...
If thats true use:

```
public boolean testParams() {
// check text 1
if (text1.equals("this shouldnt be inside") {
    System.out.println("This is an error text 1 is not what expected");
    return false;
}

// check test2
if (text2.equals("this shouldnt be inside") {
    // do sth
    .
    .
    .
    System.out.println("This is an error text 2 is not what expected");
    return false;
}
    
if(A < B && isTrue)
    return true;

// in any other case return false
return false;
```

}

If it should be a void ( so a method without any returning value) do this:

```
public void testParams() {

// check text 1
if (text1.equals("this shouldnt be inside") {
    System.out.println("This is an error text 1 is not what expected");
    return;
}

// check test2
if (text2.equals("") {
    // do sth and then at the end return with an error
    .
    .
    System.out.println("This is an error text 2 is not what expected");
    return;
}
    
if(A < B) {
    // do something when A is smaller then B
    if(isTrue) {
        // do sth when parameter isTrue is true...
    } else {
        // do another action when parameter isTrue = false...
    }
} else {
    // do something when A is greater then B
}
```

}